# ipaddr or ipv4 filter in ansible changes non quad string to quad

Tags: ansible

I am writing ansible playbook to test if an ip address is a valid ipv4 address.

I wrote a playbook to check the ip address if it's a valid ip. But for testing when I provide ip address as 10.10.10 still it is matched as a valid ipv4 address.

```
- name: IP validation example
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    single_ipv4: 10.10.10
  tasks:
  - name: check ip
    set_fact:
      single_ipv4_val: "{{ single_ipv4 | ipv4 }}"
```

> Expected result: ok: [127.0.0.1] => {"ansible_facts":
>   {"single_ipv4_val": false}, "changed": false}
>
> Actual Result: ok: [127.0.0.1] => {"ansible_facts":
>   {"single_ipv4_val": "10.10.10.0"}, "changed": false}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As best I can tell, you are running afoul of [`ipaddr`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/user_guide/playbooks_filters_ipaddr.html)'s "helpfulness" because the thing you provided is **almost** an IP address, but `ipaddr` deals with more than just IP addresses, it sniffs out subnets and all kinds of things

So what you'll want is a more strict test, saying that the input must be an IP who's ["address" subcomponent](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/user_guide/playbooks_filters_ipaddr.html#getting-information-about-hosts-and-networks) equals itself:

```
- debug:
    msg: '{{ maybe_ip == (maybe_ip | ipv4("address")) }}'
  vars:
    maybe_ip: '10.10.10'

- debug:
    msg: '{{ maybe_ip == (maybe_ip | ipv4("address")) }}'
  vars:
    maybe_ip: '10.10.10.1'
```

Comment: Thanks that helped :)